# How do I remove spaces before parameters initialization in clang-format?

Tags: c++, c, clang, clang-format

In clang-format file code is appared in the same verticle position as initial parameters. I'd like to have the initial parameters have no space but rest of the code should have space of 4 spaces(single tab size). How do I achieve the desired format?

**I have this:**

```
int main() {
    int i;
    int j; //parameters initialized
    if() {
        // stuff    //rest of the code
    }
}
```

**I want this:**

```
int main() {
int i;
int j; //parameters initialized
    if() {
        // stuff    //rest of the code
    }
}
```

**My clang-format file looks like this:**

```
# Abgeänderte .clang-format-Datei
# Anhaltspunkt ist https://clang.llvm.org/docs/ClangFormatStyleOptions.html
# sowie: https://clangformat.com

#for visual studio 2017 you have to comment this one thing:
#BreakInheritanceList: AfterColon

#version for visual studio 2017:
#Language: Cpp
#BasedOnStyle: LLVM
AccessModifierOffset: 0
AlignAfterOpenBracket: Align
AlignConsecutiveAssignments: false
AlignConsecutiveDeclarations: false
AlignEscapedNewlinesLeft: true
AlignOperands:   true
AlignTrailingComments: false
AllowAllParametersOfDeclarationOnNextLine: true
AllowShortBlocksOnASingleLine: true
AllowShortCaseLabelsOnASingleLine: true
AllowShortIfStatementsOnASingleLine: true
AllowShortFunctionsOnASingleLine: true
AllowShortLoopsOnASingleLine: true
AlwaysBreakAfterDefinitionReturnType: None
AlwaysBreakAfterReturnType: None
AlwaysBreakBeforeMultilineStrings: false
AlwaysBreakTemplateDeclarations: false
BinPackArguments: true
BinPackParameters: true
BreakBeforeBinaryOperators: None
BreakBeforeBraces: Attach
BreakBeforeTernaryOperators: false
BreakConstructorInitializers: AfterColon
#BreakInheritanceList: AfterColon
ColumnLimit:     300
ContinuationIndentWidth: 2
Cpp11BracedListStyle: false
DerivePointerAlignment: false
DisableFormat:   false
SortIncludes: false
IndentCaseLabels: true
IndentWidth:     2
IndentWrappedFunctionNames: true
KeepEmptyLinesAtTheStartOfBlocks: false
MaxEmptyLinesToKeep: 2
NamespaceIndentation: All
#PenaltyBreakBeforeFirstCallParameter: 19
#PenaltyBreakComment: 300
#PenaltyBreakFirstLessLess: 120
#PenaltyBreakString: 1000
#PenaltyExcessCharacter: 1000000
#PenaltyReturnTypeOnItsOwnLine: 60
PointerAlignment: Right
ReflowComments:  true
SpaceAfterCStyleCast: false
SpaceAfterTemplateKeyword: true
SpaceBeforeAssignmentOperators: true
SpaceBeforeParens: Never
SpaceInEmptyParentheses: false
SpacesBeforeTrailingComments: 4
SpacesInAngles:  true
SpacesInContainerLiterals: true
SpacesInCStyleCastParentheses: false
SpacesInParentheses: true
SpacesInSquareBrackets: true
TabWidth:        4
UseTab:          Never
```

Comment: Why would you want that style? It's confusing to read. Indentation level often indicates scope changes. The style you suggest confuses the reader, leading them to believe that the variables are placed in the global scope when they actually belong within the function's scope.

Comment: Hi Myst: Well, that's the prefered style of our company

Comment: I'm sorry for that. Must be confusing to read... the only solution I can think of is to use `// clang-format off` and `// clang-format on` around these variable declarations. There's probably a better answer somewhere, so I'll avoid posting anything.

Comment: What do you do with a variable defined at block scope? Does it appear on the left margin?

Comment: @ Weather Vane: Yes, it does.

Comment: Just a pedantic note: "*initial parameters*" Those aren't parameters. They're just local variables.

Comment: No, `clang-format` has no way to do that.